# Como pegar apenas o número depois da vírgula

Tags: java

Quando faço o cálculo 162/11, o resultado obtido é `14,72727272727273`. Porém quando uso o código `System.out.printf("%.1f", teste);`, é exibido o número `14,8`.

Gostaria de uma forma de guardar apenas o 8 em um `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque não fazer isso?

```
double teste = 162.0 / 11.0;
System.out.printf("%d", ((int) Math.ceil(teste * 10)) % 10);
```

A ideia aqui é:

1. Multiplicar por 10 para que o primeiro dígito depois da vírgula se torne o último dígito antes dela.
2. O [`Math.ceil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-) arredonda o número para cima. Assim sendo, o seu dígito 7 se torna um 8.
3. O *cast* para `int` corta todos os dígitos depois daquele que te interessa.
4. O resto da divisão por 10 corta todos os dígitos antes daquele que te interessa.

Como resultado, será obtido um número inteiro de 0 a 9 que corresponde ao dígito que você quer e nada mais além disso.

Além disso, há uma vantagem muito interessante: Isso tudo é resolvido apenas com matemática sem que você precise usar `String`s em momento algum.

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/kXDNwE).

Caso o desejado seja arredondar para baixo ao invés de para cima, basta substituir o `ceil` por [`floor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-). Caso seja desejado arredondar-se para o inteiro mais próximo, então pode usar-se [`rint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint-double-).

Comment: Cara, eu entendi que ele queria arredondar pra cima por que eh o numero mais proximo do inteiro que ele teria, vc poderia usar um if e testar se o mod eh menor que 0.5 e nesse caso arredondar para baixo.

Comment: @pmargreff Eu entendi que ele queria arredondar para cima porque de outra forma, 14,7272... seria arredondado para 14,7 ao invés de 14,8. Entretanto, se a ideia for arredondar para baixo, basta usar o `floor` ao invés do `ceil`. Se a ideia for arredondar para o inteiro mais próximo, basta usar `rint`.

Comment: Legal, nao sabia do rint : )

Answer (score 2):

Para o valor que segue após a virgula pegue apenas a parte depois da vírgula (funciona com positivos e negativos):

```
double valor_decimal = valor - (int)(valor);
```

Ou, caso preferir o arredontamento faça:

```
String valorString String.format("%.1f", valor);
double valorArredondado = Double.parseDouble(valorString);
```

Depois caso queira pegar apenas um número após a vírgula faça:

```
int valor final = (int)valor_decimal * 10;
```

Caso você quera formatar para todos números depois da vírgula pode tentar converter para string, e multiplicar o tamanho retornado pela função `split`:

```
String[] divisor = valor_decimal.toString().split("\\,");
int valor final = (int)valor_decimal * divisor[1].length();
```

> O problema dessa segunda solução é que ela pode estourar a
>   representação de um inteiro, para contornar isso você pode usar um
>   BigInteger para garantior que não aconteça!

---

Referências:

[SO en - How to get the numbers after the decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166756/how-to-get-the-numbers-after-the-decimal-point-java)

[SO en - Number of decimal digits in a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264576/number-of-decimal-digits-in-a-double)

Comment: Olá, funcionou bem, o problema é que com a função `System.out.printf("%.1f", teste);` ele retorna 8 e desse método ele retorna 7, eu eu precisaria do 8. Não tem como usar `("%.1f", teste)` para formatar uma variavel ??

Comment: Resposta alterada.