# Salvar valor depois da vírgula JAVA

Tags: java

Olá, preciso pegar um valor depois da vírgula para a partir dele fazer algumas operações, por exemplo, 175/10 = 17.5, preciso salvar esse valor .5 como 5. O meu número sempre será dividido por 10, podem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Porque o código que você já fez

Comment: Não entendi....

Comment: Possivel duplicação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146438/como-pegar-apenas-o-n%C3%BAmero-depois-da-v%C3%ADrgula

Comment: Eu cheguei a ver isso Adriano, porém não entendi.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode transformar ele em String e quebrar ela pra pegar o valor, dessa forma:

```
double f = 175.0 / 10.0; // f tem o valor 17.5
String s = String.valueOf(f); // converter para String

String s1 = s.split("\\.")[1]; //quebrar aonde esta o ponto e pegar o valor após

double x  = Double.valueOf(s1); //converter de volta para double
```

Note que o parâmetro do método `split()` necessita das duas barras pois o ponto é um caractere especial.

Comment: Bom dia André, obrigado pela resposta, não cheguei a utilizar o código, usei o de baixo que é mais simples e consegue fazer o que eu preciso. Abraços!

Answer (score 2):

Use o operador de módulo, que retorna para você o resto de uma divisão, que é o valor que você quer:

`int x = 175%10 //resultado é 5`

Você nem precisa dividir para depois trabalhar com o decimal. Já pode pegá-lo diretamente usando essa técnica.

Comment: Utilizei e deu certo, obrigado!!

Comment: Se a resposta lhe serviu, marque-a como correta. Isso ajuda outros usuários que tiverem dúvida como a sua.

Comment: Já positivei a resposta, mas diz que como não tenho reputação suficiente ela não aparece aqui, mas é computada.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a conversão para String, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira.

Declare e inicialize as variáveis que você utilizará:

```
double divisor = 10;
double dividendo = 175;
double resultado = 0;
int casaDecimal = 0;
```

Realize a operação de divisão:

```
resultado = dividendo/divisor;
```

Converta o resultado em uma string:

```
String resultadoString = String.valueOf(resultado);
```

Agora você realizar a operação de Split (Divisão da String) e armazenar o valor da segunda parte do split na String resultadoString (Você precisa utilizar a classe **Pattern** e o método **quote**, porque "." é reconhecido como um *regex*):

```
resultadoString = resultadoString.split(Pattern.quote("."))[1];
```

Agora é só converter a String em inteiro (no exemplo) ou double, como desejar:

```
cadaDecimal = Integer.valueOf(resultadoString);
```

Comment: Bom dia Hugo, obrigado! utilizei a forma int x = 175%10 que me retorna exatamente o que eu preciso e o código é mais simples, valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Essa forma realmente é mais simples, mas é sempre bom saber que existem diversas possibilidades de resolver o mesmo problema! Disponha!